# Long wait after login Ubuntu Gnome 13.04, probably network related

Tags: networking, gnome, login

Some basic information about my computer:

```
Ubuntu Gnome 13.04, Gnome 3.6.2.
Linux 3.8.0-34-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 18:00:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Recently it takes very long wait after I login to usable desktop (about half a minute or longer).  This happens only on the first login after a reboot, i.e. if I logout and login, no long wait.

If I boot with network cable unplugged, no long wait.

Any instructions on how to find out what was happening during that period?

UPDATE
As suggested by MariusMatutiae, I paste the last part of `dmesg -T` here.

```
dmesg -T

.....
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] init: avahi-cups-reload main process (1117) terminated with status 1
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores.
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] vboxdrv: fAsync=0 offMin=0x1f8 offMax=0x2c844
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'synchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.2.10_Ubuntu (interface 0x001a0004).
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:20 2013] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:22 2013] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:22 2013] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[Sat Dec 14 15:50:22 2013] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

But I assume the waiting / hanging-on period is after the last timestamp listed.

Comment: Take a look at dmesg -T | more

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I pasted the last part of `dmesg -T`; the whole output is beyond the length limit of a question.

Comment: Nothing wrong in that output; do you do anything like mount a network share, have a fancy /etc/network/interfaces configuration, connect to a VPN?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I usually mount a romote filesystem using `sshfs`, but I assume it has no influence after a reboot. My `/etc/network/interface` is almost empty (only `lo`) since I use the GUI configure tool. VPN, never touched.

Comment: It could instead be exactly your remote share. Try rebooting without automatically mounting the remote share, to check if this is the problem.